Can my proof be made a little bit more mathematical$?$

Given some $a\in\Bbb R^+$, define $f$ by$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a}}+\sqrt{\frac{ax}{ax+8}}.$$ Then prove that $$\forall x\ge0,\quad1<f(x)<2.$$

I know that this has been asked here before but I want to know how I can improve my proof.

We will first prove the upper bound, for this we have
$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a}}+\sqrt{\frac{ax}{ax+8}}$$
$$\implies f\left(x\right)<\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}+1+\sqrt{\frac{ax}{ax+8}}$$
$$\implies f\left(x\right)<1+1+\sqrt{\frac{ax}{ax+8}}$$
$$\implies f\left(x\right)<2+\textrm{some positive real number or 0}$$
So we have, $$\boxed{f(x)<2}$$
Now we move to the lower bound, here we have
$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a}}+\sqrt{\frac{ax}{ax+8}}$$
$$\implies f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a}}+\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+\frac8a}}$$
Now for this to be minimised, we must have $x\to\infty$ and $a\to\infty$ $\implies$ $f(x)\to1$
But here, I can't figure out from what side we approach $1$ that is, $f(x)\to1^-$ or $f(x)\to1^+$ 
from commonsense and observation, I get that its $1^+$ as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a}}$ will have more effect than $\frac{8}{a}$ but I cannot prove this mathematically.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
